# Calling the same function multiple times with different arguments?

Tags: python, function

it's me again.

Now that my function is working properly I would like to call it multiple times while changing the arguments each time I call it.

This is my function

```
def my_function(output_name, input_dir):
with open(output_name, "w+") as f:
    os.chdir(input_dir)
    for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
        duration = today - modified_date
        if duration.days < 5:
            f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")
```

EDIT1: So after messing around with the solution given by Joao Santos, I've been able to get the input for the first item in the dictionary but thats it the second and third one don't seem to work at all. If put separately they work fine, i'm a little confused...

How can I achieve this result ?

Thank you very much !!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood what you meant, but here goes ...

Add your arguments to a dictionary like :

```
arguments = {"output1.txt": "//10.2.30.61/c$\test/test\test", "output2.txt" : "//10.2.30.61/c$\test1/test1\test1", "output3.txt" : "//10.2.30.61/c$\test1/test1\test1"}
```

Then, simply iterate over that and call ur function:

```
for output_name, input_dir in arguments.items():
    my_function(output_name, input_dir)
```

Comment: Okay this is definitely working so thanks ! The problem in my case is having filled out the dictionary, when I execute the code it seems to take the first output name in this case being output1.txt and putting the info from output2 into it. It doesnt create the other 2 files nor puts the infos of those anywhere :/