# How to call a single function multiple times with different parameters in python?

Tags: python

```
list = ["a","b","c"]
def type(count):
    res2=list[count]
    for row1 in csv_reader1:   # Values imported from CSV
        res2=list[count]
        print(res2)
        res1 = str(row1)[1:-1]
        res3 = str(res1)[1:-1]
        print(res3)
type(0)
type(1)
type(2)
```

I want to call this type function, type(0) is being called, but then it exits and type(1) and type(2) are not being called. I've even tried with for loop

```
for i in range(0,2):
    type(i)
    i=i+1
```

Even this For doesn't work, it just calls type(0) and exits.

I've defined a list and I'm trying to iterate list for each value of imported from CSV.
Kind of for-each in powershell - for-each list( print res2( = list) and print(each value in CSV) ) - This is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm new to Python. Any help would  be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: HEY PLEASE TRY ANSWER OF THIS QUESTION , I THINK IT WILL HELP YOU https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64028999/calling-the-same-function-multiple-times-with-different-arguments

Comment: If `csv_reader1` is a file-like object it is exhausted after the first call to the function.

Comment: @Matthias - When I tried to print csv_reader1, this is the response - " <_csv.reader object at 0x0000025C9CC04160> "  Is there a way to convert into list of values to use in loop ?

Comment: Untested: Do something like `data = list(csv_reader1)` outside the loop and pass `data` as a second parameter (`def type(count, data):`). Then you will just have to change `for row1 in csv_reader1:` to `for row1 in data1:`.

Comment: Additionally: `type` and `list` are really bad names for functions and variables. You overwrite the built-ins with the same name.

Comment: @Matthias - data = list(csv_reader1) This worked like a charm :) I was able to get it as a list and then looped over to get the desired results. Thank you :D

Comment: But I still have one doubt regarding calling type function. When I called this function manually it is skipping. Like if put type(0), type(1), type(2) at the end after defining the type function and run them at the same time, only type(0) would get called and others are skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are creating a CSV reader something like this:

```
import csv
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    csvreader1 = csv.reader(f)
```

This reader object can only be read once and is then used up. That's why your function doesn't do anything the 2nd and 3rd times. To be able to reuse the content, use `list` to read the whole file into memory.

```
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    csv_content = list(csv.reader(f))
```

Alternatively, rewrite your function so that it reads the CSV each time.

```
letters = ["a","b","c"]
def print_data(i, filename):
    print(letters[i])
    with open(filename) as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):   # Values imported from CSV
            print(str(row)[2:-2])

print_data(0, "myfile.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["a","b","c"]
file = open("C:/Users/data.csv") 
csv_reader = csv. reader(file)
def type(count):
    res2=list[count]
    
    for row1 in csv_reader:   # Values imported from CSV
        res2=list[count]
        print(res2)
        res1 = str(row1)[1:-1]
        res3 = str(res1)[1:-1]
        print(res3)

for i in range(0,2):
    type(i)
```